# Python dictionaries of sets

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I have a dictionary

```
boxes {
    'box 1' : 'apples',
    'box 2' : 'mangoes',
    'box 3' : 'oranges',
    'box 4' : 'mangoes'
}
```

I need to regroup this dictionary as

```
fruits {
    'apples' :  {'box 1' }, 
    'mangoes' : {'box 2', 'box 4'},
    'oranges' : {'box 3'}
}
```

I tried:

```
fruits = {}
for k, v in boxes.items():
    if (v in fruits):
        fruits[v].add(k)
    else:
        fruits[v] = set()
        fruits[v].add(k)
```

I get this error: TypeError: unhashable type: 'set', and many other attempts also not working.
Please guide ! Thanks

Comment: What you've posted _works_, missing `=` in the first snippets notwithstanding. That type error would suggest you tried to use a set as a _key_, not a _value_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good case for using setdefault as follows:

```
boxes = {
    'box 1' : 'apples',
    'box 2' : 'mangoes',
    'box 3' : 'oranges',
    'box 4' : 'mangoes'
}

fruits = dict()

for k, v in boxes.items():
    fruits.setdefault(v, set()).add(k)

print(fruits)
```

**Output:**

```
{'apples': {'box 1'}, 'mangoes': {'box 2', 'box 4'}, 'oranges': {'box 3'}}
```

Comment: Sadly still getting the same error

    fruits.setdefault(v, set()).add(k)

TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'

Comment: @ABCode Did you try running the code shown in my answer?

Comment: yes, copy pasted the same. 
using spyder 5, Python 3.7.9

Comment: @ABCode Create a script with the contents of this answer and run it from a command line. I suspect something weird with Spyder but that's not something I use. The code shown is pure Python. I don't use out-of-date Python version so I can't tell if it's an issue with your version but I doubt it

Comment: I just installed Spyder 5.3.0 and ran this code with no issues. The problem you're seeing can **only** happen if the variable *v* is a set

Comment: – Lancelot du Lac THANK YOU !! IT worked. I ran it thru terminal. The restarted Spyder and it ran there too ! Strange but happy.